# ag-grid with custom filter for date field react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have created ag-grid in reactjs and typescript it is working well. But in my one of the column it is type of date field where with the help of valueFormatter and moment I am returning fromNow().

```
{ headerName: "Submitted Date", field: "LastSubmittedDate", filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter', floatingFilter: true,
        valueFormatter:(params: ValueFormatterParams)=>{
          return params.value ? moment(params.value).fromNow() : ''
        } },
```

Now I want to filter that column with number of days with greater than only. Can somebody help me. My full code is here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wpcwxj?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

please check my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fhmjqw?file=index.tsx) which i forked from your example.

what i did is that I just added `customFilterOptions`. My solution is more Javascript oriented and less redux but i guess you can get it fixed.

this is the piece of code which i added to column to make it work and only showing greater than option to end user while filtering.

```
   filterParams:{
      filterOptions:[
          'greaterThan',
          {
            displayKey: 'greaterThan',
            displayName: 'Greater Than',
            test : function(filterValue,cellValue){
              let celldate = moment(cellValue);
              let today = moment();
              let datediff = today.diff(celldate,'days')
              debugger;
              return cellValue == null || datediff > filterValue;
            }
          }
      ]
    },
```